# formatting number or string with xml xslt stylesheet not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I am trying to easily format my output of a xml structure

```
<items><item1><factor1><factor200><factor1desc><factor200descr></item1></items>
```

factor^n to numeric and factor^ndesc to string but it won't work. i do not want to enter every attribname explicit, can this be done by an auto-algo ?

```
 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(number(/*/*/*))">
        <!-- myNode is a not a number or empty(NaN) or zero -->
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </Data>
        </Cell>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- myNode is a number (!= zero) -->
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="Number">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.,'##,###.00')" />
          </Data>
        </Cell>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>   

  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: That example input is not well-formed XML, can you give us a real example of the input?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you want

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/*[. castable as xs:double and not(. = 0)]">
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="Number">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '##,###.00')"/>
    </Data>
  </Cell>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*/*/*[not(. castable as xs:double) or . = 0]">
  <Cell>
    <Data ss:Type="String">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Data>
  </Cell>
</xsl:template>
```

But if you want to write one template and then in the template you want to test the matched element then change `<xsl:when test="(number(/*/*/*))">` to `<xsl:when test=". castable as xs:double and not(. = 0)">`.

I was not sure whether NaN is converted to false but I have now checked so your test with `<xsl:when test="number(.)">` should do as well.

Comment: this is not working, because with visual studio 2010 i can only use 1.0 here is my output ID Projektnummer Projektname Bauherr_Kunde Nutzungsverhaeltnis Jahr_Datenerfassung Postleitzahl Stadt Anschrift Land Bundesland Datenherkunft
1.00 3,312.00 NaN NaN NaN 2,008.00 70,732.00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: Sorry for making an XSLT 2.0 suggestion, but the question is tagged as `xslt-2.0`. Microsoft does not have an XSLT 2.0 processor but there are third party solutions, both for .NET (XmlPrime, Saxon) or COM (AltovaXML).